# There is much of the cast and crew being like a family

Tags: grammar, reading

I was reading a film review on the newly-released documentary *Harry Potter 20th anniversary* until one sentence caught me out:

> Chats among the three main stars, Daniel Radcliffe (Harry himself),
> Emma Watson (Hermione Granger) and Rupert Grint (Ron Weasley), take
> place in the Gryffindor common room, there’s an opening set piece in
> the Hogwarts dining hall, Radcliffe and director of the first two
> films, Chris Columbus, talk in Dumbledore’s office and so on. It
> provides a rush of nostalgia only heightened as the enduring affection
> among them all becomes evident. **There is much – rising perilously if
> perhaps inevitably close to emetic levels – of the cast and crew being
> like a family**. There always is in programmes like this, but at least
> here it is more than usually justified. The actors famously began
> working on the franchise when they were children, and their audience
> grew up alongside them pretty much in real time as the films were
> released between 2001 and 2011.

To give you more context, I have quoted the entire (lengthy) paragraph above and highlighted the sentence **in bold type**. I am wondering what the word "much" refers to: is it a pronoun used to refer to the word "affection" in the previous sentence? Or is "there is much of something" a set phrase?

Another question is about the ending part "being like a family": does it function as a modifier for "the cast and crew"?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The earlier sentences refer to *chats* and *talking*. There is much in these conversations (a great deal is said) about the cast and crew being like a family. (Presumably there was a 'family' atmosphere on set, maybe many of them have kept in touch.)

*Much* can be understood to mean 'much talk/discussion'.

Comment: Now it makes perfect sense. Thank you Kate!